# Module name is doubled

Tags: magento

I was create a module, its my xml file in etc/modules/Tim_Lastadded.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Tim_Lastadded>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Tim_Lastadded>
    </modules>
</config>
```

When I'm open PA in section Advanced I have doubled module name
[image]
I cant find a reason of doubled.
Thx for help

Comment: hi, please search in app/etc/modules/ whether you have Tim_Lastadded should be repeated or may coming due to cache issue , flushh all ur caches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `app/code/local/Tim/Lastadded/etc/config.xml`. If you specify a version there, make sure that `<Tim_Lastadded>` is the same (watch the case sensitivity).

Answer (score 0):

check app/etc/modules/ on your server to see if you have two files:

```
Tim_Lastadded.xml
```

and

```
tim_lastadded.xml
```

delete the lower cased file, and then refresh Magento cache and it should be fixed :)

Comment: In app/etc/modules/  I have only Tim_Lastadded.xml

Comment: File name in this directory is arbitrary except for `.xml`

Comment: yes but if he had accidentaly added another with lowcase letters you could have two with the same name in there and it would cause the above issue as Magento would load both.